# IdentityServer 3 hanging on the GetConfiguration() call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, identityserver3

I have just started working on IS 3 project which is already there. The architecture we currently have is

1) WCF REST and WCF Soap in one WCF service project
2) Owin middle layer which is a class library which is a separate project
3) Identity Server 3 which is a web project within the same solution as the previous 2

I have just added a brand new Web API project (Ver 1) into the same solution and I am trying to utilize the same code, so that I can share the calls with the WCF project.

I have implemented separate classes called HttpHeaderInformationForWebAPI and all that and I am sending my ApiControler.Request object all the way to this Owin layer.

If I try a request for the existing WCF Rest method, the code works fine and it validates the token just fine.

But when I try to validate the token via my new Web Api, it hangs at this line.

```
private async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> RetrieveConfiguration()
            {
            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(IDPBaseAddress + "/.well-known/openid-configuration");
            configurationManager.AutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
            return await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

It hangs at the return await line and just hangs there. If I look at the IdentitySerever logs, it says "Starting Discovery" and hangs there. Am I missing any config entries?

As far as I know the Middleware is handling everything and I don't need any web.config values at my end other than the Base Address and other end point URLs related to IS.

Can you please let me know what I am missing? Most of the samples are within the same project on GitHub. Here it is a 3-tier setup and I am really struggling if I need anything in Global.asax on my API project. If I look at the existing WCF service project, there is nothing configured related to OWIN or IS or no startup.cs and it works fine. But the same line hangs when called from my web api,  even though I can get that config file to load on my browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Take out `ConfigureAwait(false)` to see what happens as your code is already async .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! Trying now

Comment: Unfortunately its the same result. These are the final 2-3 log statements on the IS side.

Comment: 2019-03-14 19:44:03,440 [1] WARN  IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory - RefreshTokenStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
2019-03-14 19:44:03,440 [1] WARN  IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory - Using custom redirect URI validator - you are running with scissors.
2019-03-14 19:44:04,026 [7] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpointController - Start discovery request

Comment: I also looked at the source code for IS 3 and searched for that comment (Start discovery request).  The only difference between my HttoRequestMessage and the one on the existing WCF project is, I am passing my HttpRequestMessage all the way, as a variable.

Comment: I compared the ConfigurationManager object when I make a call in the "working" scenario with the existing REST service Vs my new call.  I am not sure what to make of this. But properties like _docRetriever and _configRetriever are all being displayed directly under configurationManager in the watch window, in my case. Whereas all those properties are nested under "Non-Public Members" in the case where it works.